# PayPal REST SDK Deprecated

Tags: java, spring-boot, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I implemented Pay Pal in my spring boot app using pay pal rest SDK. Now I can do payments successfully but when I tried to implement refund using pay pal sdk the pay pal documents gives warning message "SDK is deprecated so use Pay pal direct API calls".

Pay Pal Document - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/quickstart/install/

Can any one tell me will I face problems in future if I use Pay pal SDK??

Comment: Typically a deprecation notice has time mentioned till functionality is supported. If I were you I would not use any deprecated feature as it will be an extra effort for me to re-implement the solution once functionality is removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old v1/Payments SDKs are deprecated

You should use the new v2/Checkout SDKs instead: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/